# Passing XML File To xml2js With Node.js

Tags: node.js, xml, xml2js

**Background**

I have taken some sample data from a large `XML` response I will be working with in my app. I decided to save the xml to a `response.xml` file in my app so I can parse the data without making a bunch of unnecessary request to the api.

I am going to be using `xml2js` to convert the xml response to a `JS` `Object`.

**Problem**

I have been able to open the file and `console.log()` it.

I have been able to run `xml2js` by passing a small xml string to it which I also `console.log()` it.

But I have only been able to `console.log()` the file after xml2js creates the object. No matter what I try I continue to get null when using return or passing trying to pass the data outside of the initial creation of the object.

**Example**

This prints `xml tree` to the console,

```
var fs = require('fs');
var openFile = fs.readFile('./response.xml', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
});

function requestCreditReport() {
    return openFile;
}

requestCreditReport();
```

This prints a small `xml string` to console statically added in with 
`xml2js`,

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>";

parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

**Question**

How do I use the object once it is created outside of the method below. Initially when it is created I can output it to the console but cannot seem to access it outside of that `console.log()`. in the example below I am trying `return result`. This leaves the value null when I try to pass the object returned by the function to a variable like this,

```
var response = requestReport();
```

Recent try,

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

function requestReport() {
    fs.readFile('./response.xml', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        return parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            return result;
        });
    });
}

var response = requestReport();

console.log(response);
```

This returns `null`. But if I console.log(result) instead or using return then trying outside of the function it returns this,

```
{ RESPONSE_DATA:
   { '$': { MYAPI: '0.0.0' },
     DETAILS: [ [Object] ],
     DETAILS_ACCOUNT: [ [Object] ],
     RESPONSE: [ [Object] ] } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

requestReport is async. It doesn't return anything so response is undefined.

You have to use a callback.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

function requestReport(callback) {
  fs.readFile('./response.xml', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    parseString(data, callback);
  });
}

requestReport(function(err, result) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: If I wished to store/return 'result' instead of printing to the console how would I do this?